# Build 2015 Triggers - Continous Integration, trigger on changes in any path defined in repository

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, repository, azure-pipelines

Build 2015 vNext Triggers - Continuous Integration, trigger on changes in any path defined in repository

If i define a vNext Build in the on-Promise Version and i want it to run as a CI Build (Continuous Integration) i have to define the whole list in the trigger section, which i already defined in the repository, again.

i want my ci-builds to run, if changes happen in any of the tfs paths defined in the repository. But for achieving that, i always have to copy paste everything from repository to the trigger - ci part.

Its annoying and time consuming especially because the ci trigger definition also doesn't get cloned if you want to define a new build out of an existing one.

May anyone have come along with that also and may have something in mind which could make it easier and less time consuming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature or setting by default, as Repository and CI filter are used for different purpose:

> Repository specifies which files will be downloaded from your remote
>   repository into a local sources directory by build agent at the
>   beginning of the build process.
>
> CI filter selects the version control paths you want to include and
>   exclude.

An idea to have CI filter the same as Repository mapping by default has been [submitted at the Visual Studio User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/16267636-build-2015-vnext-triggers-continous-integration), Microsoft Product Team will evaluate it carefully.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i entered a new suggestion

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/16267636-build-2015-vnext-triggers-continous-integration